# protractor java script - send var which created in 'it' to other 'it'

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm creating the 2 foloowing var in the first 'it' funtction: 'theCurrentAccount;' , 'switchToAccount;'

```
  var theCurrentAccount;
  var switchToAccount;

it("should find the current account", function () {
    ptor.findElements(protractor.By.xpath("...")).then(function (elements) {
        if (elements.length > 0){
            theCurrentAccount = context.switchAccount.accountName1;
            switchToAccount = context.switchAccount.accountName2;
        }
        else{
                theCurrentAccount = context.switchAccount.accountName2;
                switchToAccount = context.switchAccount.accountName1;
        }

    });
});


switchAccount(ptor, switchToAccount);
```

now when I call the function switchAccount which defined like this :

```
var switchAccount = function (ptor, id) {

    it("should switch account to" + "'#" + id + "'", function () {

    });
}
```

id in not defined. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: `ptor.findElements()` looks like it might be asynchronous. `.then` indicates there is a `Promise` involved. Can you verify this?

Comment: maybe you dont undestand me? after the first 'it', the var 'switchToAccount' get correct value (checked) . the problem is that the value of 'switchToAccount' as param here : 'switchAccountIfNotInIt(ptor, switchToAccount);' is determined before and thus, is value is undefined

Comment: If the code is synchronous `switchToAccount` should be defined when you call `switchAccountIfNotInIt`, but you say it's not. Put a `console.log` statement below the `it` iterator and in the `then` callback. Which one fires first?

Comment: the one below the 'it' , but how can i do it correctly?

Comment: You need to attach the call to `switchAccount` to the state of the Promise created by `ptor.findElements(protractor.By.xpath("..."))`. I'm not familiar with the framework you're using so I can't give any direct code examples.

Comment: I know i can do it, but it not good in this case - because it will cause 'it' inside 'it' - wrong thing. do you have others solutions?

Answer (score 0):

First the synchronous parts of the code are read through and executed, and then the deferred statements are resolved. Interactions such as `findElements` will always be deferred, but you can insert your own commands into the controlFlow queue as well.

```
var theCurrentAccount;
var theOtherAccount;

var switchAccount = function() {
    if (theCurrentAccount === 'name1') {
        theCurrentAccount = 'name2';
        theOtherAccount = 'name1';
    } else if (theCurrentAccount === 'name2') {
        theCurrentAccount = 'name1';
        theOtherAccount = 'name2';
    }
};

it("should find the current account", function () {
    expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe(undefined);
    expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);
    switchAccount();
    expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe(undefined);
    expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);

    ptor.findElements(protractor.By.xpath("...")).then(function() {
        theCurrentAccount = 'name1';
        expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe('name1');
        expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);
        switchAccount();
        expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe('name2');
        expect(theOtherAccount).toBe('name1');
    });

    expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe(undefined);
    expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);
    switchAccount();
    expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe(undefined);
    expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);

    browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
        expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe('name2');
        expect(theOtherAccount).toBe('name1');
        switchAccount();
        expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe('name1');
        expect(theOtherAccount).toBe('name2');
    });

    expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe(undefined);
    expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);
    switchAccount();
    expect(theCurrentAccount).toBe(undefined);
    expect(theOtherAccount).toBe(undefined);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Define these `browser.params`, which are static variables across the execution:

```
broswer.params.theCurrentAccount = context.switchAccount.accountName1;
broswer.params.switchToAccount = context.switchAccount.accountName2;
```

These parameters works as static and can be accessed across all the specs